# 2D RMS calculation

Tags: matlab, 2d, rms

I am trying to calculate the rms of some 2D matices, but am unsure if my approach is correct:

```
Rrms = sqrt( sum(sum((Z1 - mean(mean(Z1))).^2 )) /(wk*wl) )
```

(where `Z1` is a matrix with size `wk * wl`)

Is this correct, and if not, what should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Root Mean Square](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Root-Mean-Square.html) definition it's just square root of sum of squared values.
In terms of Matlab code it will be.

```
R = sqrt(sum(sum(Z.^2))/prod(size(Z)))
```

Another way is to use [rms](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/signal/ref/rms.html) function from signal processing toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this request is obsolete. However, try

```
Rrms = rms(Z1(:))
```

In any case, the `(:)`-operator helps!